# Loop through characters in array, for each possible combination of 3 characters run code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code, I want to loop through all of the characters in an array, and for each possible combination of 3 characters, execute the following code, then repeat until it has reached all the possible combinations

I have no idea where to start, please help if you can

This is my code, thanks

```
var link = 'http://www.roblox.com/UserCheck/DoesUsernameExist?username=';
var swap = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
//get all combinations of 3 objects in the swap array, for each do this:
$.get(link+(the combination of three objects here)).success(function(r) {
    if (r['success'] == false) console.log(the combination of three objects here);
});
```

Comment: Can the combinations be out of order? ('cab', 'bac', etc)

Comment: I don't care so long as all combinations are ran, and it won't repeat combinations

Comment: Do you have the implementation of DoesUserNameExist() which is the function that is being called through the url?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a fairly complex and relatively time-consuming program to implement this.  There are no built in functions that will do this for you.  I will not implement the function for you as it will take me more time than i'm willing to spend, and it will be good and even fun for you to do.  But here are some suggestions I have.

You will need to implement a decision tree to come up with all of the possible combinations or permutations you want.  (if you don't know the difference between a combination and a permutation, start by looking that up.)

Next, research decision trees.  A decision tree will be the process your algorithm follows to make a possible combination.  In short, it will make a number of three-element arrays, or three-character strings.  It will start with, say, 'a'.  It will then branch off and make a new array or string that starts with 'a' for each potential element that could follow 'a'.  So one decision branch would place the 'b' as the second character.  Another branch would place 'c' as the second character, a third would place'd' after the 'a', etc.  Each of these two-character branches (one for each possibility) would then in turn each branch off for the possible options that each one has for its third element.

This is most often done with recursive functions but could also be iterative. (look these up if you don't know what they mean.)  If you have 30 elements in your original array, the number of possible permutations of three will be something like 30^3; depending on whether you allow for repeats.

If the order doesn't matter, a combination is what you want, and this will be a bit simpler to implement, but still a fairly involved algorithm.

Hope this gives you enough help to start googling.  Come back with more specific questions if you need.

TL;Didn't Edit

Comment: Would having a loop that just randomly selects 3, and they are added into an array of already scanned combinations, and if the 3 are not in the scanned combination it scans them?

Comment: "random" means not predictable, how would you know that your program will ever finish? In theory, it could choose the same numbers over and over again.

Comment: True, but the chances of that are extremely slim

Answer (score 0):

It will need to make P(36,3) = 42840 requests which will take a lots of time. In case you still want to execute this, you can look for permutation calculator like [in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743007/most-efficient-way-to-write-combination-and-permutation-calculator-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You will get them all using a triple-nested each :

```
$.each( swap, function(index1, char1){
    $.each( swap, function(index2, char2){
        $.each( swap, function(index3, char3){

            var combination = char1 + char2 + char3; // Will give you "aaa", then "aab", then "aac"...
            // do stuff

        });
    });
})
```

However, the total number of combinations is 36 x 36 x 36 which is 46656. You don't want to make that many ajax calls simultaneously :)